# Change text of update and cancel button in create popup window

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid looks like this:

```
<div id="grid" data-bind="kendoGrid: {
    data: dataSource, 
    groupable: false, 
    scrollable: true, 
    pageable: { pageSize: 10 },
    sortable: {
        mode: 'multiple',
        allowUnsort: true},
    toolbar: [{ name:'create', text:'' }],
    ...
</div>
```

How can I change the text of the 'Update' and 'Cancel' button?

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `command` column in your Grid with an `Edit` and `Delete` button? If so, you should define there the text for `update` and `cancel`. Something like:

```
toolbar: [
    { name:'create',  text : 'Crear' }
],
columns   : [
    {
        command: [
            {
                name: "edit",
                text: { edit: "Editar", update: "Actualizar", cancel: "Cancelar"}
            },
            { name: "destroy", text: "Borrar" }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/kqNRy/

If not, you can do the trick of defining it as before and then configuring this column as hidden:

```
toolbar: [
    { name:'create',  text : 'Crear' }
],
columns   : [
    {
        command: [
            {
                name: "edit",
                text: { edit: "Editar", update: "Actualizar", cancel: "Cancelar"}
            }
        ],
        hidden: true
    },
    ...
]
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/kqNRy/1/

Comment: This solution only provides the same update text for Create and Edit. What if I want to have different texts for different operations? (e.g 'Create' should have an 'Insert' button, while 'Edit' should have an 'Update').